# how to add class to tag when i click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add `class="active"` to tag  `<li>` when i click on `<a>` to become `<li class="active">`

Notice i have multiple `<li>` tags and i need to `class="active"` only for tag `<li>` that i clicked on it.

this my sample code :

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>
   <a href="...">
    Personal Informations <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="...">
    Qualifications <i class="pe-7s-note2"></i>
   </a>                              
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/addclass

Comment: If the answer helped, please 'accept' it

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent()` and `.addClass()`

```js
$(function(){

  $('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
<li>
   <a href="#">
    Personal Informations <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#">
    Qualifications <i class="pe-7s-note2"></i>
   </a>                              
</li>
</ul>
```